# PlayFramework 2.x - Forms / Associating error message to one element of a tuple

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I've got this form mapping:

```
val myElement = Form(
    mapping(
      "title" -> nonEmptyText,
      "schedule" ->
        tuple("startSchedule" -> jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
          "endSchedule" -> jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))
          .verifying(MyValidator().checkForEndScheduleConsistency("error.schedule")),
    )(MyElement.apply)(MyElement.unapply)
  )
```

`MyElement` class:

```
case class MyElement(title: String, schedule: (Datetime, Datetime))
```

`MyValidator` class:

```
def checkForEndScheduleConsistency(errorMsg: String) =
    Constraint[(DateTime, DateTime)]("constraint.schedule", errorMsg) {
      schedule =>
        MyDomainValidator().checkForEndScheduleConsistency(schedule._1, schedule._2, Messages(errorMsg)) match {
          case Success(s) => Valid
          case Failure(f) => Invalid(ValidationError("custom error string from `f`"))
        }
    }
```

Requirement: An error message must be associated to the field `schedule.endSchedule`(tuple's element) if the schedule is inconsistent according to `MyValidator` object.

However, in order to have both required elements (`startSchedule` and `endSchedule`) available for `checkForEndScheduleConsistency` method, I can't apply a `verifying` method directly on the nested tuple's element named `endSchedule`. Instead, I have to apply one on the whole tuple in order to include `startSchedule` variable, as shown in the code snippet.

The drawback is that the error is not mapped to `endSchedule` but to `schedule` (that doesn't represent anything in my HTML form), and so nothing is displayed to screen when an inconsistent schedule appears.

Therefore, I have to use this "workaround" to achieve my requirement using `Form`'s `withError` method:

```
def create = Action {
    implicit request =>
      myForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        myFormWithErrors => {
          myFormWithErrors.error("schedule") match { //check for the presence of potential schedule error
          case Some(e) => {
            BadRequest(views.html.create_element("Create an element", myFormWithErrors.withError("schedule.endSchedule", Messages("error.schedule"))))
          }
          case _ => BadRequest(views.html.create_element("Create an element", myFormWithErrors))
        }
        },
        myForm => {
          treatSubmittedMyForm(myForm)
        }
      )
  }
```

=> Very ugly and anti-DRY.

Is there a way to apply `verifying` on the tuple and despite of that, apply the error message to a nested tuple's element? In my case, on `endSchedule`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best solution is to replace the default helpers provided by Play when rendering the field by one of your own making, as per [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFormHelpers):

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

That way you can manually replace the error reference to the right element. Not extremely nice but you should be able to create a reusable tag from it.

Comment: Not a bad idea :) I will try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to precise the global (to schedule) "error" key into the more specific generated input directly, here the `schedule.endSchedule` input:

```
@inputText(hobbyForm("schedule.endSchedule"), 'id -> "schedule.endSchedule", '_error -> hobbyForm.error("schedule")
```

Notice the part: `'_error -> hobbyForm.error("schedule")`